# Teleporting other players than myself

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So far I have:

```
testfor @p[r=30,name={playername}]
```

and I want it so it will look for players without that name. I managed it before on a different world that's now deleted without using a scoreboard.
How do I it again?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `=!` operator, which basically means "A Is unequal to B". If you want to target a player with the Testfor, it would look like this:

```
/testfor @p[r=30,name=!PLAYERNAME]
```

If you want to teleport all the players that satisfy this constraint, then you should use the `@a` target selector, which targets **all players**. A teleport command would then look as follows:

```
/tp (x y z) @a[r=30,name=!PLAYERNAME]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use that :

> /tp ~ ~ ~ [playername]

You must don't run this command in command_block.